# How do I read a node.js traceback?

Tags: node.js

Node.js rookie here.  I get this stack trace when my application crashes:

```
/private/var/folders/ds/jt45ngkn40x012pyb8mtc0j00000gn/T/shelljs_9498e871f54d195af8d1:10
    fs.writeFileSync(fname, err.code.toString());
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
    at /private/var/folders/ds/jt45ngkn40x012pyb8mtc0j00000gn/T/shelljs_9498e871f54d195af8d1:10:37
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:259:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:887:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:340:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:546:12)
exec: internal error
```

How do I get from this to a line of code?

Comment: Is events.js your code?

Comment: It's an open source project - I do have a file called events.js, but there's a comment at line 125.